# Pyspark Pivot Duplicate values in one column to get all unique values for following Rows

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created a join of 4 tables and now I have following table now ,

[image]

As you can see, column = `tconst` have duplicate values because there were some unique value in column one, two, three, four

I want to do have this result now ,(removing duplicate `tconst` value and all unique values in the duplicates `tconst` value are listed by increasing columns)

[image]

Can you please help me how to get this result, (nothing can be changed in join of four databases, now need to create a logic of getting this result, and order do not matter as long as i have unique values, please help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = dataframe.groupBy('tconst').agg(f.concat(f.collect_list('one')))
```